# puppeteer gets stuck on popup window

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialog, popup, puppeteer

I encountered a strange website that puppeteer cannot get by. Here is the link.
https://www.aliveandcooking.com.au/index.php/recipe/baked_blt_club_sandwich

When I visit the site I get a popup, saying that I need to update my Macromedia Flash. (That probably indicates that it's an old site.)
[image]

I tried using

```
page.on("dialog", ...);
```

That didn't work. Any idea how can I dismiss this dialog with puppeteer?

Answer (score 4):

The reason I did not detect the dialog popup is because I put the `page.on` eventListener after the `await page.goto`. With the correct order the code worked perfectly:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setViewport({
    width: 1024,
    height: 768
});
page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    console.log(dialog.message());
    await dialog.dismiss();
});
await page.goto(link, {
    timeout: 20000,
    waitUntil: [ 'load' ]
});
```